# Delete file and get objects list from Amazon S3

Tags: list, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file

I have developed several classes for classic asp (REST)

```
uploadFile.asp
deleteFile.asp
getListObject.asp
```

After testing, I was surprised at the result:

1. Uploaded file to the server
2. Deleting a file
3. Get list objects

The file remains on the list

I use cloudberry explorer and see that file no exist.

In what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Maybe it's problem of classic asp. I needed a dynamic query string. When I use an alternative authentication method and it works.